# JMeter altering values in .xls files using bean shell processor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I have a JMeter script where I should access a .xls file with multiple tabs and alter values .
The .xls file has values like , **RASD1234,TWER1234,ZAST1234** . I should change the numeric value to unique values each iteration like **RASD1235,TWER1235,ZAST1235** in all tabs  . How can I achieve this in JMeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [tika-app.jar](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) and put it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Once you do this you will be able to use [POI-HSSF](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/) API to edit the Excel file

Just one piece of advice: [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider doing this in Groovy (normal Java syntax will also work)

References (including code snippets)

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)